# Fade Unfocused objects in CSS

Tags: css, object, fade

I was wondering if it was possible to have a selection of three items, all of which have an opacity of 1 when they are not hovered over, and to some how have the other two items have half the opacity, or "fade", when I hover over one.

Here is what I have tried so far, unfortunately, it has proven unsuccessful, as the opacity of the object which I hover over remains at .5.

```
 #mainLinks:hover { opacity: .5; }
 #mainLinks a{
      margin: 10px -10px 10px -10px;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s;
 }
 #mainLinks a:hover{
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      opacity: 1.5;
 }
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Just ask me if you need more information or clarification!

Thanks,
Owen

Comment: You'll more than likely need JavaScript (very simple JavaScript) to do this. Although, I have an upvote waiting for a CSS3 solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

1. The parent needs to have the full opacity set to .5
2. The hovered item will need the opacity set to 1

Example HTML:

```
<ol id="items">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ol>​
```

CSS:

```
#items:hover > li { opacity: .5; }
#items:hover > li:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

​I left out the transitions / transforms from your example, but I assume you get the idea.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rS7ZR/)**.